# Weak Convergence to Normal Distribution (Central Limit Theorem)

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n$ be independent random variables such that $X_1 = 1$, and for $n \geq 2$,

$P(X_n=n)=n^{-2}$ and  $P(X_n=1)=P(X_n=0)=\frac{1}{2}(1-n^{-2})$.

Show $(1/\sqrt{n})(\sum_{m=1}^{n}X_m-n/2)$ converges weakly to a normal distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I believe I will be using Central Limit Theorem for this problem, but I am not sure how to apply it. Help/hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb E[X_n] = \frac{n (n+2)-1}{2 n^2}$ and $\mathrm{Var}(X_n) = \frac{(n-1) (n+1) (n (5 n-4)+1)}{4 n^4}$.